# Consulta MySql para base de datos de 1 TB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

Buenos días, me encuentro con el problema de que por tamaño de la consulta, me es imposible ejecutarla, e inviable troceararla en trozos muy pequeños porque no se acabaría nunca. 
Me encuentro usando el framework Laravel 5.5, pero aun así decidí por rendimiento no usar Eloquent.

Lo que necesito realmente es actualizar una columna con el valor de otra pero pasandole `html_entity_decode()`

```
 $main_query_sql = "SELECT id, Body FROM emails WHERE mensaje IS NULL";
            $main_query     = $db->prepare($main_query_sql);
            $main_query->execute();

            $query_sql = null;

            while ($email = $main_query->fetch()) {
                $query_sql = "UPDATE emails SET mensaje = :mensaje WHERE id = :id";
                $query_sql     = $db->prepare($query_sql);
                $query_sql->bindParam(':mensaje', html_entity_decode($email['Body']));
                $query_sql->bindParam(':id', $email['id']);
                $query_sql->execute();
```

Todo esto esta también en una transacción, pero no llega a entrar en el while.
Tengo cambiados los parámetros de mysql y apache para no tener limites, tanto en archivo como en tiempo de ejecución y aun asi me da un `PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1853882368) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes)` en un servidor dedicado solo a esto con requisitos mas que de sobra.

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    DB::disableQueryLog();
    \Debugbar::disable();

PD: por si a alguien le vale para entender lo que tenia antes

```
Email::select('id', 'mensaje', 'Body')->whereNull('mensaje')->chunk(100,
                function ($emails) {
                    $email = null;
                    foreach ($emails as $email) {
                        $email->mensaje = html_entity_decode($email->Body);
                        $email->save();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: 1TB?!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Nosotros tenemos consultas con millones de resutlados, y lo que hacemos es efectivamente trocearlas. Con seleccion de id. Del 1 al 5mil, del 5001 al 10mil y asi...

Comment: Si, 980 GB para ser mas concretos, aunque puedo dividirlo en fragmentos de 10GB sin problemas al estar distribuidos, pero no menos.

Comment: @GDP no es viable trocear en 5k cuando tienes billones, pero si me pones ejemplos lo pruebo a ver si se satura.

Comment: Lo de 5mil era un ejemplo. A ver si luego tengo acceso al proyecto. Era una app movil que necesitaba consultas con millones de resultados, cosa que saturaba la bbdd y la red. Por lo que se lanzaban miniconsultas. de 500k por ejemplo. COnsecutivas.